# How to hide Bootstrap textbox toggle on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a couple of dynamically created buttons with toggle boxes below it that are created like so.

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="accordion-toggle btn btn-default btn-small" 
data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion'+this.id+'" 
href="#collapseOne'+this.id+'"><i class="icon-info"></i></button>
```

Here is the textbox collapse it calls to display on click

```
<div id="accordion'+this.id+'">
    <div id="collapseOne'+this.id+'" class="collapse" style="height: auto;">
        <div class="control-group control-group-notes">
            <button onclick="clearMsgBox(\''+this.id+'\')" type="button" class="close" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion'+this.id+'" href="#collapseOne'+this.id+'">x</button>
            <textarea id="doGet'+this.id+'" style="width: 92%;" rows="2" placeholder="Message..."></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The button and boxes are dynamically created and works fine. The only issue I can't seem to figure out is that on load all the boxes are open and not hidden. But once I click the x button it toggles to hide just fine.

Could anyone help me out? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @KyleMit data-parent="#accordion'+this.id+'" works just fine. I just had to remove the heigh:auto and in. Thank you anyways :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bootstrap the class="in" determines the visibility of your accordion and it's probably present on all of them when it loads.

```
class="panel-collapse collapse in"
```

For those you do not want to show onload remove the "in" class.

Comment: That's what I just noticed, But it seems even removing it still causes it to show on load

Comment: Looks like you resolved it i should get some credit ;)

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

If anyone wants to the know what was causing it.

As stated above in class needed to be removed. also there was a height auto that needed be removed.

code as follows.

```
<div id="accordion'+this.id+'">
    <div id="collapseOne'+this.id+'" class="collapse">
        <div class="control-group control-group-notes">
            <button onclick="clearMsgBox(\''+this.id+'\')" type="button" class="close" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion'+this.id+'" href="#collapseOne'+this.id+'">x</button>
            <textarea id="doGet'+this.id+'" style="width: 92%;" rows="2" placeholder="Message..."></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your div to be hidden on load, you can try to set: "display:hidden;" in your CSS for this div. Then the toggle function will show it on click by changing the display attribute. (at least this is how it works with jquery)